# Does the C++ standard support processes?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know C++11 added support for threads. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void bar()
{
    std::cout << "bar()\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread(bar);
    thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

However, is there a way to execute the `bar` function in a separate process? If not, is there any discussion on whether such a feature should be added?

**Note:** I'm aware of the possibility of using platform independent libraries and I'm just curious if C++ supports this directly or will in the future.

Comment: @MarcB That's not a C++ standard function is it? In other words, it has to be provided by a specific compiler, right?

Comment: `fork` is not in the standard library, it's a posix function.

Comment: \*checks C++11 standard\* No. \*checks C++14 standard\* Nope. \*checks [C++17 draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft)\* Nopedy nope. And as far as I know, there's no intention to include this into the language standard (yet).

Comment: No - C++ is not aware of a process or shared process memory or similar ...

Comment: The standard mentions Interprocess communication in 29.4 [atomics.lockfree]p3, but in a note.

Comment: There's no support specifically for processes in the standard, but you could use a library like Boost ( See http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/ for Boost.Process) if you need process support.

Comment: You might look at boost. http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/

Comment: @JamesAdkison: To support threads, the C++ language had to be changed to make threads *possible*. Before C++11, the language had no way of even talking about multiple paths of execution though the same program. Processes need no such language changes. It's a pure library construct.

Comment: Or Qt http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html

Comment: Thanks, to those pointing out platform libraries (e.g. Boost and Qt) and I'm  already aware of them. I tried to include a note in the question (at the bottom) that states I'm purely curious if that was in the C++ standard or planned for inclusion. But multiple comments have stated this is not currently supported or expected.

Comment: Is this even possible on Windows without complex IPC trickery? Process forks are a cheap and easy thing on POSIX but non-POSIX systems behave very differently.

Comment: @JustinTime, ThomasMcLeod : that library appeared 10 years ago, and it has not been included in Boost, yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, the c++ standard (particularly C++11) doesn't have any notion of a *process* (hence I can't give you a more reasonable reference here as a [search result](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=fork&button=) from the most popular and currently most up to date c++ documentation site).

I'm also not aware that process support is planned for the next standard version C++-17 (aka C++-1z). At least the [Wikipedia Site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) doesn't mention it.

There is a popular [implementation](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) that was proposed for boost, but that never was drawn for a C++ standard proposal.

You usually can't write portable code to run on bare metal systems, where only one *process* exists.

---

> However, is there a way to execute the `bar()` function in a separate process?

The simplest option to do that is to fallback to [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) and [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) as specified by the POSIX Open Group:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void bar()
{
    std::cout << "bar()\n";
}    

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // child process
        bar();
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        // parent process
        wait(NULL);    
    }
    else
    {
        // fork failed
        std::cerr << "fork() failed!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

---

Though I don't see much of a point to create an extra process to execute a simple function. Creating a process creates a lot of overhead you don't want in such case.

Well, if you want to start another program using functions from the `exec()` function family that's a different use case.

**I'd recommend sticking to `std::thread`s for your example.**

Comment: The sample code in the question is just for illustration. I wouldn't actually try to run that in a separate process.

Comment: @JamesAdkison So your question is about starting another executable from your code as I mentioned with my hints about usage of the `exec()` family functions? The only function supported by the c++ standard is `std::system()` AFAIK, but it has it's limitations.

Comment: note: this solution doesn't scale well in Windows, which is very slow to execute a `fork` equivalent.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, I was curious about running the code in a separate process, not launching a separate executable. Perhaps my example is just confusing the issue? I just really wanted to know whether C++ supports or plans to support processes and the overwhelming evidence seems to be "No."

Comment: @JamesAdkison _"and the overwhelming evidence seems to be "No."_ Exactly, that's what I wanted to point out as clearly as possible with my answer. Stick to threads for your sample, you don't need another process, everything necessary is already shared in the threads.

Answer (score 4):

Boost started supporting processes in version 1.64.0 (April 2017).

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/process.html

The fact that it is a Boost feature is a source of hope for its inclusion in a future C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [proposal in 2019](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1750r1.pdf), but the momentum seems to have stalled a bit since.
See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/511) for progress about it.