# executing a function within a process C++

Tags: c++, process

I have this code witch works great (it's for a report at school, but now it needs a little enhancement).
This is the code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void insertRandomNumbers(){
    int xRan;
    srand(time(0)); 
    fstream file; 
    file.open("test.txt", fstream::out);
    for (int i = 00; i < 1000; i++){
        file << (rand() % 10000 + 1) << endl; 
    }
    file.close();
}

vector<int> readNumbersFromFile(){
    std::vector<int> data;
    std::ifstream DataFile("test.txt");

    if (DataFile)
    {
        int value;
        while (DataFile >> value)
        {
            data.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    return data;
}

void displayVector(vector<int> numbers){
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it<<endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();
    insertRandomNumbers();
    vector<int>numbers = readNumbersFromFile();
    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    displayVector(numbers);
    t2 = clock(); 
    float difference = (((float)t2) - ((float)t1));
    cout << "Time needed to create a file, insert 1000 random numbers,\nsort the numbers and then displey them in the console :  " << difference / 1000 <<"s\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As I said it works fine, but now I need to put every function I call in the main function in a different process, each waiting for the last to complete before it starts (I know it's pointless, but a teacher wants it that way. What can you do, right?)
The problem is I don't even know where to start, I've searched through the net and forums and I can't find a good and EASILY understandable answer, so I turn to you guys :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you need separate processes? Not threads? You know the difference between processes and threads?

Comment: May be you shold creating threads instead of process? In this case `std::thread` is you choice.

Comment: For real multiprocess programs, the key word you're looking for is **IPC** (stands for Inter-Process Communication). You're also looking for [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). But see Adi Levin's comment.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300580/does-the-c-standard-support-processes/35300820#35300820

Comment: If you do not know where to start, start with reading! **Do not** search for *answers*, or *examples*. Open the book and read a chapter called *Interprocess Communication* (for your operation system). Then try to code a solution. Than, when it doesn't work (it is expected!) go back to stack overflow, provide your code and ask specific questions. So far, i am voting to close your question.

Comment: Is it too mundane to suggest that you ask your teacher? There are a number of ways of achieving what you want, but I'm guessing that the key to your success is choosing the one that your teacher has covered in class.

Comment: no processes, NOT threads, like i said it's for school (i know it doesn't make sense)

Comment: well it makes sense, it he wants to teach you, how to fork processes, to wait for child processes to finish, and how they use pipes to communicate